# How to transform the column values to another pattern in DataFrame, Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The values in 2nd-8th columns in DataFrame named `df` has a pattern like `{'close': 'time1', 'open': 'time2'}`, for example, `{'close': '21:00', 'open': '11:00'}`.

How can I change all the values that have this pattern to **time2-time1**, such as **11:00-21:00**?

[image]

Comment: Show us df.head()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `apply function to call a custom algorithm to manipulate your dictionaries:

```
df.Monday.apply(lambda d: '-'.join([d['open'], d['close']]) 
                          if isinstance(d, dict) else d)
```

Comment: Remove it, I added that to account for the closed all day cell you have

Comment: I've found the problem. I need to replace all the single quotes to double quotes so that its type is dict. Your method works well. Thank you!